# Error when reading graphml file in r graph

Tags: igraph, graphml

I'm trying to read a graph ml file in r using the i graph package.

The code I'm using is the following

```
g<-read.graph("graph_bustuberail_london_500m",format=c("graphml")) #import gml
```

I get the following error message
Error in .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_graphml", file, as.numeric(index),  : 
  At rinterface.c:5866 : Cannot open GraphML file, File operation error

Not sure why this is not loading in, can anyone help me?

Comment: `Cannot open GraphML file, File operation error`   is the file in the current directory?  Is the file actually named "graph_bustuberail_london_500m.gml" (with the file extension)?

Comment: Yeah I've managed to solve this by manipulating the code ever so slightly - still unsure as to why the original wasn't working.

Comment: g_L<-read_graph("graph_bustuberail_london_500m.graphml",format="graphml")

Answer (score 0):

Igraph is not very informative regarding certain types of error it displays: I have found that many times the above error is caused by simply a misspelling in the filename.

As a consequence I suggest you to start by checking that you have written the file extension correctly, i.e. with `.gml` ending and not with `.glm`.